# Passing references (And Unity's WWW.progress) to Coroutines/IEnumerators

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, coroutine, ienumerator

I've made a coroutine within C# using Unity 5 and I'd like to pass a reference to it. It didn't seem to work so I made a test script to try to isolate the following error.
`error CS1623: Iterators cannot have ref or out parameters`

Here's the test script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TEMP : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        float var = 3.141f;
        StartCoroutine ( test (ref var) );
    }

    IEnumerator test (ref float value) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            Debug.Log (value);
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

In addition, on my actual script, I'm using Unity's WWW class to download something, and I also get this error when I pass www.progress as a reference:
`A property or indexer 'UnityEngine.WWW.progress' may not be passed as 'ref' or 'out' parameter`

Comment: Well yes, you can't use `ref` parameters with iterator blocks. What are you actually trying to achieve here? Note that "as a reference" isn't the same as "by reference"... are you *sure* you need by-reference behaviour?

Comment: Does this actually have anything to do with unity3d, or is that just distracting from the question?

Comment: @roryap The WWW.progress bit at the end of the question is related to Unity3D

Comment: What do you think that passing `value` as a ref parameter actually does here?

Comment: @DavidG Well, I would expect passing `var -> value` as a reference would mean that if I change the variable var, it would affect the reference of `value` in the coroutine

Comment: That really doesn't make much sense. Can you explain what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @DavidG In my script. I'm using Unity's WWW class to download a file from the internet within a coroutine. That coroutine yields until the download has completed. In the meanwhile, I have another coroutine to display the download progress to the user. I'd like to pass a reference of www.progress to the coroutine to display the progress. While I could get www.progress from within the coroutine itself, I'd also like to reuse it for other purposes (when I want to use it, but to not display www.progress)

Comment: @DavidG Would it just be easier to not yield the coroutine that downloads the file and make it write to a global variable, that is then accessed by the coroutine that is displaying the progress

Comment: I don't understand your question  :)  But you can nowadays EFFECTIVELY pass a reference to an iterator, very easily, just using a lambda and an Action: http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/551381/view.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the ref from the function arguments.

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    float var = 3.141f;
    StartCoroutine ( test (var) );
}

IEnumerator test (float value) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        Debug.Log (value);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Based on your requirement you could do something like below with an out parameter. I'm not exactly sure how you are intending to use these methods but I think you are getting the wrong idea about ref arguments and how they work.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float var = 3.14f;
        StartCoroutine(test(var), out var);

    }

    static IEnumerator test(float value)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
            yield return value + 1;
        }
    }

    static void StartCoroutine(IEnumerator test, out float update)
    {
        update = 0;
        while (test.MoveNext())
        {
            update++;
            Console.WriteLine("Executing..." + update);
        }
    }
}
```

However you are never going to be able to pass a ref or out parameter to the interator.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: OK Updated it to be an answer

Comment: Do you mean this: `StartCoroutine ( test (var) );` ? I still get the same error...

Comment: Updated my answer with an example. The error is coming from the fact that the anonymous function assigned to test variable is declared to accept a ref which is not allowed for iterators.

Comment: That's not quite what I'm looking for. I'd like to make it so that if I change `var`, it changes `value`. That's why I'd like to use references

Comment: @LeeDale I don't think you should be calling this an "anonymous function", in C# that means something [completely different](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb882516.aspx).

Comment: @DavidG sorry your right, when I first looked I just had anonymous method in my head for some reason.

Comment: The edit's still not quite what I'm looking for (Or am I missing the point. I'm new to coroutines and refs...) I still accepted your answer though because of the 1st point (remove the refs). I'm just using a variable which I can write to while the coroutine runs, which the coroutine reads.

Comment: Yes its not really an answer to your problem, that would take a bit of a re-structure of the code. Without knowing how you are exactly using it, it would be a bit hard to come up with something that would work.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that

```
IEnumerator test (float value)
{
  for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
  {
    Debug.Log(value);
    yield return null;
  }
}
```

Is syntactic sugar for something like:

```
private class Iterator : IEnumerable<object>, IEnumerator<object>
{
  private int _state;
  private int _threadId = Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId;
  private object _current;
  private float _value;
  int i;
  public Iterator(float value)
  {
    _value = value;
  }
  public object Current‎
  {
    get { return _current; }
  }
  object IEnumerator.Current
  {
    get { return _current; }
  }
  public IEnumerator<object> GetEnumerator()
  {
    // If we're on the same thread and its the first call, reuse this object as the enumerator
    // otherwise create a fresh one for new call (so we don't have buggy overlaps) or a different
    // thread (to avoid a race on that first call).
    Iterator iter = _state == 0 && _threadId == Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId ? this : new Iterator(_value);
    iter._state = 1;
    return iter;
  }
  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
  {
    return GetEnumerator();
  }
  public bool MoveNext()
  {
    switch(_state)
    {
      case 1:
        i = 1;
        _state = 2;
        goto case 2;
      case 2:
        if (i <= 10)
        {
          Debug.Log(_value);
          _current = null;
          ++i;
          return true;
        }
        _state = -1;
        break;
    }
    return false;
  }
  public void Dispose()
  {
  }
  public void Reset()
  {
    throw new NotSupportedException();
  }
}
private IEnumerator test(float value)
{
  return new Iterator(value);
}
```

Now, consider that your `float` parameter has become a `float` field in the implementation. Since you can't have a `ref` field, you can't have it as syntactic sugar for what looks like a `ref` parameter.

Hence your approach not only won't work (C# won't do it for you with `yield` taking away a lot of the coding) but can't work.

You'll need to box the float in some way, whether you are holding onto a `object` reference to the same float, that as a reference-type can be updated by the iterator, or a typed box like:

```
private class TypedBox<T> where T : struct
{
  public T Value { get; set; }
  public TypedBox(T value)
  {
    Value = value;
  }
}
```

That again allows you to access the value via a reference-type, but without the casting cost.

More often its more useful just to have the value iterated based on any values passed in.